# Viewstate hidden field so big it makes everything crash

Tags: .net, asp.net, viewstate, chunking

For some reason the viewstate of my application became gigantic (around 14 million characters). It adds around 1 minute of loading time. If the page finally loads (which is not often), the server crashes every time someone send a form because "`Post size exceeded allowed limits.` "

It appeared suddenly. I didn't add any fields, just some javascript on the page.

People told me to check viewstate chunking out. Google told me to do this:

```
<pages maxPageStateFieldLength="1024">
```

... so now instead of a huge hidden field I now have something like 100 very large hidden fields. It's not exactly what I was looking for.

Why would .NET do something like this? How can I fix this?

Comment: Any chance you can turn off viewstate for a few of the controls?

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at the page, but try a viewstate decoder to see what's being embedded in the viewstate.

You should also turn off viewstate of grids/tables if you don't need them and perhaps implement a compressed viewstate in addition to turning on gzip on IIS.

Comment: The controls are input fields and there is no way to turn off the viewstate for those and even if it was that would require me to re-write a lot of code. Also there are like 10 fields, it shouldn't be that bad... right?

Comment: @mikael: how do I turn off viewstate of grids/tables? I only have input fields, is it possible that .net decided that some other fields needed to be in the viewstate?

Comment: What are you using the viewstate for on the inputs? If you just need them to remember their values across postbacks, that'll work without viewstate.

Comment: There's obviously something else going on if you only have 10 fields.  Are you using custom controls that use resources?  How did you add the javascript to the page?

Comment: @chris: To remember values and use them in my backend as well... I mean I can refactor this, but is it even possible to turn off the viewstate for these? Last time I checked it wasn't working as I would expect

Comment: @womp: I generate javascript server side. I've got a couple of loops in the asp and that's pretty much it

Comment: @marcgg Textboxes will retain their value across postbacks even without viewstate enabled.

Comment: @chris: it would be nice to find an answer that doesn't implies that I have to rewrite too much code, and disabling the viewstate for everything would be a bit violent. If there's no other way I'll do it... but not happilly :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using a utility to decode your viewstate so you can get an idea of what is actually within it (since you obviously have a lot of information in there you don't seem to need.)

A [viewstate decoder](http://www.o2-platform.com/wiki/DotNet/ViewState_Decoder_ASP.NET_2.0) will allow you to see what's in your viewstate that you aren't expecting.  Then you can either modify your code, remove the offending control, or selectively disable viewstate (using the `EnableViewState="false"` attribute) for the controls that shouldn't have it enabled.

Comment: That's annoying, the software crashes, apparently the string is too large. But now I know that my viewstate is 13 428 604 characters long :)

Comment: It finally run without crashing on my 5th attempt :) It looks like it's putting all my page in the viewstate... it's quite weird. I'll try to see what's the logic here and come back on SO

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I accept your answer because you're the one that lead me in the right direction... even thought Chris' answer also helped me a lot. The problem was that this page was a search page... and for some reason it included all the results in the viewstate even though there was no search done. I saw that using the viewstate decoder. Then fixing it was simple, I added EnableViewState="false" on the .ascx that kept the search results and it fixed it. yay!

Comment: @marcgg That was what I ment by turning off the viewstate :) Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that controls will retain their values across postbacks without viewstate. You can often disable viewstate for a lot of your controls without any issues. To disable viewstate for a specific control set:

```
EnableViewState="false"
```

If you set this for all of your grids and any controls that you don't need viewsate for it will significantly reduce the size.

Comment: I did this and it didn't change anything. I'm including .ascx files like this: <uc1:attributeAutocomplete EnableViewState="false" runat="server" id="_temposAutocomplete" ></uc1:attributeAutocomplete> and there's quite a lot of JS going on in there. Could it be linked? I disabled the viewstate for these and it didn't fix it

Comment: I figured it out (see accepted answer)! I accepted beska's because it's the answer that helped me figure out the issue, but yours was also helpful... so +1 and thank you very much :) !